# Microsoft Word Paste Special Paste Link Shortcut

Tags: vba, ms-word

I had a quick question in regards to using the paste special option in Microsoft Word.

I want to set a shortcut so that I can do something like CTRL Q or right click and have the option and it would do paste special paste link and unformatted text and I want this to work in any word file I open.

Ideally I would like the unformatted text to be the same font style and size as is currently set, but I know that this would be more difficult and I don't know how to do this in Word VBA.

I know that I need to do something like:

```
public sub 
  PasteSpecialUnformatted()
  selection.pastespecial Link:=True, datatype:=wdpastetext,
  Placement:=_wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
end sub
```

However, I have never done VBA programming in Excel so I don't know if my code is correct and I don't know how to edit the hot keys **`(ctrl + whatever)`** or the right click menu.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I also should note that I am using Microsoft Version 2013.

Comment: So I figured out how to add in paste special as CTRL Q but I am still having difficulty with adding it into my right click options and I have no idea how to set the font and size of the text to the current settings.

Comment: Have you considered adding it to the QAT?

Comment: If you're pasting as unformatted text then it should be picking up the font settings of the target range. As it should when you paste manually? As to the right-click menu: for that you need to define a Ribbon XML customization. You'll find a list of resources at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ba8c9d0b-7312-4503-8167-f2ef86f17435/information-on-the-office-fluent-ui-ribbon-for-developers?forum=officegeneral. The basics are in "Customize the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for developers (1 of 3)" and specifics about right-click menus in "Customize context menus in Office 2010"